# ComponentScan or EntityScan don't find entities in another project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jpa

I have spring boot project in which I import entities from my other spring boot project.

Dependence on a project with entities is as follows

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>models</groupId>
        <artifactId>models</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The main project is configured as follows

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableZuulProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "model.entity")
public class SecurityService {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run(SecurityService.class, args);
    }
}
```

I've tried using @ComponentScan and @EntityScan. I tried to delete these projects from the .m2 directory but I always get the same error (attach as screeshoot) [stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U712.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you have to specify the package name from the dependency

Answer (score 1):

it is my mistake, I forgot add

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```